# Tornado + aioredis: why are my redis calls blocking?

Tags: python-3.x, redis, async-await, tornado, python-asyncio

I try to build on Tornado and with Redis a simple system with two API endpoints:

1. an API reading a value from Redis, or waiting until this value exists (with `BRPOP` : `value = yield from redis.brpop("test")`)
2. an API writing this value (with `LPUSH` : `redis.lpush("test", "the value")`).

So I expect to be able to call those API in any order. Indeed, If I call 2. then 1., it works as expected, the call to 1. returns immediately with the value.

The problem is, if I call 1. then 2., both requests block to never return.

Concurrently, while the requests block, I can still `LPUSH`/`BRPOP` directly in Redis, even to the same key. Similarly, I can call other Handlers in Tornado. So I guess the block is situated neither in Redis nor in Tornado, but in my use of aioredis? Maybe the asyncio loop? But I can't understand where I'm mistaken. Any tip?

Thanks for any help.

Here is my code:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado import web, gen
from tornado.options import options, define
import aioredis
import asyncio


class WaitValueHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def get(self):
        redis = self.application.redis
        value = yield from redis.brpop("test")
        self.write("I received a value: %s" % value)


class WriteValueHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def get(self):
        redis = self.application.redis
        res = yield from redis.lpush("test", "here is the value")
        self.write("Ok ")


class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.configure('tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop')

        handlers = [
            (r"/get", WaitValueHandler),
            (r"/put", WriteValueHandler)
        ]

        super().__init__(handlers, debug=True)

    def init_with_loop(self, loop):
        self.redis = loop.run_until_complete(
            aioredis.create_redis(('localhost', 6379), loop=loop)
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = Application()
    application.listen(8888)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    application.init_with_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I saw why, [as the doc states](http://aioredis.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0/migration.html#blocking-operations-and-connection-sharing) :

> Blocking operations (like blpop, brpop or long-running LUA scripts) in shared mode mode will block connection and thus may lead to whole program malfunction.
>
> This blocking issue can be easily solved by using exclusive connection for such operations:

```
redis = await aioredis.create_redis_pool(
    ('localhost', 6379),
    minsize=1,
    maxsize=1)

async def task():
   # Exclusive mode
   with await redis as r:
       await r.set('key', 'val')
asyncio.ensure_future(task())
asyncio.ensure_future(task())
# Both tasks will first acquire connection.
```